# (Qt)I want to know why the if statement won't be excuted

Tags: qt

I want to make a simple timer by Qt. When I want to implement pause and resume functionality,it seemed that the if statement in `void Widget::on_Pause_clicked()`didn't work .
widget.h:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>
#include <QString>
#include <QLCDNumber>
#include <QMouseEvent>
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QLCDNumber *lcd;
    QTimer *ptime;
    QTime *timerecord;
    QPoint windowPos;
    QPoint mousePos;
    QPoint dPos;
    bool isStart;
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

private slots:
    void on_Start_clicked();
    void updatetime();
    void initTime();
    void on_Pause_clicked();
    void on_Clear_clicked();

public slots:


};
```

widget.cpp:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ptime = new QTimer;
    timerecord = new QTime;
    ui->Timer->setDigitCount(11);
    initTime();
    connect(ptime,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(updatetime()));
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);//remove system border
    isStart=false;//determine if the timer is running
    ui->Start->setEnabled(true);
    ui->Pause->setEnabled(false);
    ui->Clear->setEnabled(false);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::initTime()
{
    timerecord->setHMS(0, 0, 0);
    ui->Timer->display(timerecord->toString("mm:ss:zzz "));
}

void Widget::updatetime()
{
    *timerecord = timerecord->addMSecs(1);
    ui->Timer->display(timerecord->toString("mm:ss:zzz "));
}

void Widget::on_Start_clicked()//when the start button is clicked
{
    ptime->start(1);
    isStart=true;
    ui->Start->setEnabled(false);
    ui->Pause->setEnabled(true);
    ui->Clear->setEnabled(false);
}

void Widget::on_Pause_clicked()//when the pause button is clicked
{
    if(isStart == true)
    {
        ptime->stop();
        ui->Pause->setText("继续");
        isStart=false;
        ui->Start->setEnabled(false);
        ui->Pause->setEnabled(true);
        ui->Clear->setEnabled(true);
    }

    if(isStart == false)
    {
        ptime->start(1);
        ui->Pause->setText("暂停");
        isStart=true;
        ui->Start->setEnabled(false);
        ui->Pause->setEnabled(true);
        ui->Clear->setEnabled(false);
    }



}

void Widget::on_Clear_clicked()
{
    ptime->stop();
    initTime();
    ui->Start->setEnabled(true);
    ui->Pause->setEnabled(false);
    ui->Clear->setEnabled(false);
}

void Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)//make the window movable
{
    this->windowPos = this->pos();       
    this->mousePos = event->globalPos(); 
    this->dPos = mousePos - windowPos;   
}

void Widget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)//make the window movable
{
    this->move(event->globalPos() - this->dPos);
}
```

Comment: The problem is your ```if``` statements are in sequence.  So any changes to ```iStart = false``` in the ```if(isStart == true)``` block, will be caught by the ```if (isStart == false)``` block.   You should use ```else``` and not ```if (isStart == false)```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
void Widget::on_Pause_clicked()//when the pause button is clicked
{
    if(isStart == true)
    {
        ptime->stop();
        ui->Pause->setText("继续");
        isStart=false;
        ui->Start->setEnabled(false);
        ui->Pause->setEnabled(true);
        ui->Clear->setEnabled(true);
    }

    if(isStart == false)
    {
        ptime->start(1);
        ui->Pause->setText("暂停");
        isStart=true;
        ui->Start->setEnabled(false);
        ui->Pause->setEnabled(true);
        ui->Clear->setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

if `isStart` starts out to be true, then it enters the first if condition block.  Within it, `isStart` becomes `false`.

However, when it exits that block, it hits the `if (isStart == false)` block and since `isStart` is false, therefore it goes into that block and changes `isStart` to `true`.

What you should do (bear in mind my qT is rusty):

```
void Widget::on_Pause_clicked()//when the pause button is clicked
{
    if(isStart == true)
    {
        ptime->stop();
        ui->Pause->setText("继续");
        isStart=false;
        ui->Start->setEnabled(false);
        ui->Pause->setEnabled(true);
        ui->Clear->setEnabled(true);
    } else  {
        ptime->start(1);
        ui->Pause->setText("暂停");
        isStart=true;
        ui->Start->setEnabled(false);
        ui->Pause->setEnabled(true);
        ui->Clear->setEnabled(false);
    }

}
```